# Are there any comprehensive spas ("wellness") in Prague?

Tags: budget, europe, prague, central-europe

I'm thinking of very nice experiences I have had in Grimbergen and Boetfort in Belgium. These spas had heated indoor and outdoor pools, hot tubs, steam rooms, and saunas of various temperatures and interiors. Not to mention places to lay down and relax.

I've been to a spa in Pardubice that had all of these amenities, but I haven't heard of anything in Prague. It would be nice to find one in the range of about the 1000 CZK per person for a couple of hours. Within an hour's drive of Prague would be the farthest I would be willing to travel.

Comment: What do you mean by `nice`? As it stands this question might be too subjective.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. By nice I mean a place that has all the things I mentioned in the body of the question. Plus clean, fluffy towels, and a reasonable price (aprox 1000 kr per person for at least a few hours).

Comment: Add the budget constraint to the question.

Comment: How far away from Prague is acceptable? There's an option in Podebrady, 50km away.

Comment: I upvoted your question but do you really require towels? I have been to many very nice spas in the Netherlands, Germany, Austria, etc. and you invariably have to bring your own towels/bathrobe (or buy – not borrow or hire – one). Is it different in Belgium?

Comment: Haha. No towels not required. Just a plus. Even in Belgium we brought our own, but you could pay 2 EUR or so to borrow one.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Note that you could post your own find as an answer instead of an edit. That way, it's more visible and can be upvoted.

Comment: hi @Relaxed, thanks, I wasn't sure if it really answered the question satisfactorily, but I guess it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several beer spas in Czech and a couple in Prague. It's an *"interesting"* experience

In Prague, there are:

- [Beer Spa Bernard Prague](http://czechbeertours.com/beer-spa-bath-prague) (around 2500 CZK, 90-100 Euros)
- Pivní Lázně BBB Tábor

(Source: http://www.praguebeergarden.com/news/post/beer-spas-czech)

For more traditional Spa/Massage:

- [Augustine Spa](http://assets.augustinehotel.com/lps/assets/u/Augustine-Spa-Menu-ENG.pdf) (around 3000-4000 CZK, pretty expensive stuff)
- [Ecsotica Spa](http://www.alchymisthotel.com/en/ecsotica-spa/bodytreatments/) (around 2500-3000 CZK)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really want to go there too, especially because I enjoy Bernard, but it isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Just checked out the link to Augustine. They have a day pass to their wellness area (which is more like what I was thinking about), and it is under 900 CZK.

Answer (score 2):

I found a great place called Saunia at the Gallerie in Nové Butovice. It has at least 5 types of sauna and a steam room, relaxation areas, cold pool shaved ice, and cold water buckets. Only thing missing from my requirements are the pool and hot tub. For 2 people for two hours we paide 450 CZK. Towels were included :D